# Rdlc Report Action "Go To URL" Can't Read Externel Image URL

Tags: c#, reporting-services, rdlc, reportviewer

I added An Action "Go To URL" To Textbox in Tablix in a Rdlc Report.

When I Add URL Like "http://www.google.com" The Report Read This URL Well and When I Click This Textbox The Browser Start With This URL.

I Tried To Change This URL to Navigate To an Image On My Local Host Like "file:///C:/Users/MSF/IMG_0042.JPG" but I get an error:

> The Report Can't Read This URL

And When I Click The Textbox The Browser Not Start.

Answer (score 0):

Are you putting your path in double-quotes?

This works in my expression:

```
="file:///C:/tmp/testac.bmp"
```

Comment: i tried it not working too.
when i add expression in the texbox it become clickable but when click the brower not opening

Comment: Did you try with a folder on your C: drive (like a **C:\TEMP** folder)? The issue may be in permissions getting to your USER folder.

Comment: yes i tried another file in another destination but the same problem the report viewer open browser only when the URL have "http://" i tried to put "www.google.com" as a URL but it the browser dose not opened when i change the URL to "http://www.google.com" the browser started and worked well and i can't add "http://" to a link of a file in local host

Comment: OK I was incorrect - I thought it was a permission issue. I was judging by the following the link in the Action window that it was working. It looks like I had used network path instead of the file path before: `="FILE:\\server\group\Good.bmp"`

Comment: firstly thank you for your concern :)
I tried this path also the same problem happened